# Mathematica: FindFit gives a solution, but it is not correct?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to fit data:

```
data={{30.,3837.71},{93.75,3900.6},{300.,3962.19},{937.5,4040.79},{3000.,4113.21},{7500.,4174.15}};
```

To the following model:

```
model = H0*(1 - (1/Kstab*Log10[10^10*H0/(2*Kstab*x)])^0.5);
```

I am using:

```
FindFit[data,
   model, {{H0, 6000}, {Kstab, 100}}, x];
```

Mathematica gives me the following solution:

```
{{HZero->6548.42},{Kstab->59.7248}}
```

However, if I try the fitting in Microcal Origin, I get :
HZero=6441, and Kstab=139, which is in fact the good solution.

Please, would you have suggestions on how to get better solution in Mathematica?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why is the second fit better ?

```
model[x_] = H0*(1 - (1/Kstab*Log10[10^10*H0/(2*Kstab*x)])^0.5);
sol = FindFit[data, model[x], {{H0, 6000}, {Kstab, 100}}, x];

model1[x_] = model[x] /. sol;
model2[x_] = model[x] /. {H0 -> 6441., Kstab -> 139.};
```

The residuals are :

```
Total[(#[[2]] - model1[#[[1]]])^2 & /@ data]
(* 75.0659 *)

Total[(#[[2]] - model2[#[[1]]])^2 & /@ data]
(* 4.15003*10^6 *)
```

Graphically :

```
Show[Plot[{model1[x], model2[x]}, {x, 30, 7500}], ListPlot[data]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Curious. I wonder why the OP said _"which is in fact the good solution."_